# The last request from the server deletes the previous requests when the requests made simultaneously

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I have no idea how to explain it since I have no experience with MVC, so If you need more information please let me know. I made a web-application, based on MVC core. Using this application, the user gets access to his blockchain account. The problem begins when 2 users at least make a request from the server. The last request deleted the previous requests, and put it's information instead -  and I have no idea why. I presumed that each request is made in a different thread, but it seems that it doesn`t work as I thought.

For example, User A login to his account - Account A. The server returns him the first view.

At the same time, User B login to his account - Account B. The server returns him the first view too

Later, when User A click on some links that leads to another view, the view been loaded with the details of User B (the last user that made the request from the server). And that not how the server supposes to work!! Am I miss something on MVC?
How can I fix this bug?

Comment: The account detail kept in a static class

Comment: In addition, I'm running the application in VS 2019. Are there any limitations that I am not aware of?

Comment: IMO, you have met the [Concurrency conflicts](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/concurrency).Also, you could refer to the similar [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: There is one problem with your links. The accout details not coming from DB, but from the blockchain network using c# class (API)

Comment: Maybe a dictionary <public-key string, c# class account> will solve the problem. In each post to the server the view will deliver the public key (=address) to the server

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use static class to save user details. Static class can have only static members, which means for all request, these member are the same. In your case, when user A login, then static class is set with user A data, but when user B logins class is set with user B data and when request from user A come back, there is no more details about user A, it is overwritten by user B. More about static classes [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members).

You should save user details in session, you can read about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Your right, but the problem is that I noticed this problem too late, I tried to use session, but this requires the account class to be serializable. The problem is that I got some properties into the account class which are part of the blockchain API ( Nethereum) and they are not serializable. I used static dictionary. It similar to session.